# Replace dll on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, publishing

Want to replace dll files on IIS without restarting IIS or stop website but everytime i replace it gives error files are in use by other process.Is there any way to replace dll files on IIS without restarting IIS or stopping website.Googleed it but got answer its not possible.Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to overwrite the existing dll files even when the website is running. Replacing the whole bin folder is not possible, but replacing dlls is.

IIS reset isn't needed when updating the dll files (or anything in the bin folder) because the application will automatically recycle

Comment: That seems odd. Are you sure it is iis that is using it and not an other program?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

The DLL will remain in memory as long as the IIS services is running. After replacing the DLLs You should do an IIS reset, So that the assemblies replaced are compiled and loaded.

Comment: i m replacing dll but its giving me error file in use by another process ....what should i do ?

Comment: You shd stop your website and then start.